# The import servletUriComponentsBuilder cannot be resolved

Tags: java, rest

I have add the servlet dependency yet, also updated meven project. but it not fixed.

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;
{
 String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("/downloadFile/")
                .path(fileName)
                .toUriString();
```

}

Comment: You are missing a dependency. Please show us you pom so we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

The [`ServletUriComponentsBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/ServletUriComponentsBuilder.html) type can be found in the [`spring-webmvc`](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.springframework%20a:spring-webmvc) artifact:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thank you.I add this dependency already. but not right. I defined a class called ServletUriComponentBuilder and build it like original .

Comment: @thien I really hope you didn't create your own `ServletUriComponentBuilder` as you stated in your previous comment. That's non-sense.